# Count the number of colors of images

Tags: java, image, colors

I have three different images (jpeg or bmp). 
I'm trying to predict the complexity of each image based on the number of color of each. 
How could I make it possible with Java?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
These codes doesn't work .. the output shows 1312 colors even it only plain red and white

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class clutters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("1L.jpg"));    
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);     
                int red   = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                int green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
                int blue  =  pixel & 0x000000ff;                    
                Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);     

                //add the first color on array
                if(colors.size()==0)                
                    colors.add(color);          
                //check for redudancy
                else {
                    if(!(colors.contains(color)))
                        colors.add(color);
                }
            }
        }
system.out.printly("There are "+colors.size()+"colors");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does a grayscale image (with a mere 256 colors) inherently have less complexity than a color image image with as many as 65,536 colors?

Comment: What you're trying to construct is called a histogram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is basically right, whereas too complicated. You could simply use a `Set` and add the `int` value to it, as existing values are ignored. You also don't need to calculate the RGB values for each color, as the `int` value returned by `getRGB` is unique by itself:

```
Set<Integer> colors = new HashSet<Integer>();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));    
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);     
            colors.add(pixel);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are "+colors.size()+" colors");
```

The "strange" number of colors you are getting is owed to image compression (JPEG in your example) and maybe other reasons like anti-aliasing of your image editing software. Even if you paint only in red and white, the resulting image may contain a lot of colors in between of these two values on the edges.

That means the code will return the *real* count of colors used in a particular image. You might also want to have a look on the different image file formats and lossless and lossy compression algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29

has an getRGB method that might be useful. But as you can see in this class. Counting colours is not a trivial things as there are a variety of color codings and there are also alpha channels to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(...);
bi.getColorModel().getRGB(...);
```