# Count the difference of colors

Tags: java, colors

My question is related to the previous question:
[Count the number of colors of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153504/count-the-number-of-colors-of-images)

Is there any way to count the difference between colors (e.g. luminance)?
If the difference between the two colors were too small, it will automatically considered as 1 color instead of two colors. This way, what people perceived of the number of colors of image will be more close with what the computer counts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now you're trying to calculate Delta E. Perhaps a color science and/or imaging science book would be a wise investment :)

See this previously answered question for the information you seek:

[Compare RGB colors in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968179/compare-rgb-colors-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can get luminance by:

```
 luminance = (int) (redValue + greenValue + blueValue);
```

To get the main idea review the use of redValue, greenValues and blueValue.
[Check this Picture.java](http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/ice-gt/uploads/1043/Picture.java)

code from **Barbara Ericson ericson@cc.gatech.edu**