# How can I do a method that return the Color that is more times repeated? all values of RGB that the image has

Tags: java, c, colors

Is something like:

public Color colorMoreTimesRepeated()
{

}
and I don't know how to make a variable that count the different colors and return me the one that is repeated more times.

The idea is to count all the colors of an image and give the color that is repeated more times, I have tried using *2 journeys with for and when a anycolor is repeated it begins to count and at the end it return the one that is more repeated.

```
    count=0;
    Color moreRepeated = null;
    for(int i=0;i< high;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<wide;j++){ *
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent answer to this on Stackflow. I've posted the code below as well as a link to the discussion.

```
Set<Integer> colors = new HashSet<Integer>();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));    
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);     
            colors.add(pixel);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are "+colors.size()+" colors");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253698/2353014

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Bjen's answer, to actually count them:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> rgbCounts = new HashMap<Color,Integer>();
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));    
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
        // count it;
        Integer count = rgbCounts.get( pixel);
        rgbCounts.put( pixel, (count != null) ? count+1 : 1);
    }
}
```

For you to do -- find the highest Count in the map, and return the Color from RGB.